# Extraction of variables from text, with completely different formatting, using Python

Tags: python, text, formatting

The text is formatted in the following manner:

```
0 -> 1
3 -> 2
2 -> 6,5
8 -> 7
5 -> 9,4,1
```

On the left there is always one number and on the right there may be multiple.

And this is what i try to yield, a list with this kind of formatting.

```
lst = ['01', '32', '26', '25', '87', '59', '54', '51']
```

Please don't ask what i have tried so far, because any attempts, using strip and split, led to something very far from what I'd like see.

Comment: Why the need to not use loops? And are you producing strings here, or integers?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Martin i edited the question. I need them to be strings not integers.

Comment: @dawg I guess loops are needed at least to iterate over the lines of the text. So i edited my question.

Comment: I just tested your answers and they both work. I upvoted them but i don't know which one is fair to choose as accepted.

Comment: Choose Martijn Pieters. He was first with a really good answer. Only choose a second answer if it is better (which mine is not...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do use loops, anyway. Here is a generator to produce your output:

```
def genoutput(iterable):
    for line in iterable:
        first, second = (l.strip() for l in line.split('->'))
        for value in second.split(','):
            yield first + value.strip()
```

Now you can loop over the generator, or convert the output to a list:

```
with open('inputfilename') as infh:
    lst = list(genoutput(infh))
```

Demo:

```
>>> example = '''\
... 0 -> 1
... 3 -> 2
... 2 -> 6,5
... 8 -> 7
... 5 -> 9,4,1
... '''.splitlines()
>>> def genoutput(iterable):
...     for line in iterable:
...         first, second = (l.strip() for l in line.split('->'))
...         for value in second.split(','):
...             yield first + value.strip()
... 
>>> list(genoutput(example))
['01', '32', '26', '25', '87', '59', '54', '51']
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
txt='''\
0 -> 1
3 -> 2
2 -> 6,5
8 -> 7
5 -> 9,4,1'''

output=[]
for line in txt.splitlines():
    lh, rh=map(str.strip, line.split('->'))
    for e in map(str.strip, rh.split(',')):
        output.append(lh+e)

print output 
# ['01', '32', '26', '25', '87', '59', '54', '51']
```

Answer (score 1):

Comprehension method;

```
print [i for i in [[x.split(' -> ')[0] + y for y in x.split(' -> ')[1].split(',')]
for x in '''0 -> 1
3 -> 2
2 -> 6,5
8 -> 7
5 -> 9,4,1'''.split('\n')] for i in i]
```

**Edit:** simplified the if statement

Recursive method;

```
def paraToListRecur(para):
    if para != []:
        first = para[0].split(' -> ')
        return [first[0]+x for x in first[1].split(',')] + paraToListRecur(para[1:])
    return para

data = '''0 -> 1
3 -> 2
2 -> 6,5
8 -> 7
5 -> 9,4,1'''.split('\n')

print paraToListRecur(data)
```